# Can we ONLY customize the Display/View SharePoint list form using Power Apps, while keep using the SharePoint built-in Create/Edit list forms

Tags: sharepoint-online, development, powerapp, powerapps-forms

Inside our SharePoint online communication site >> we want to customize the View/Display list form for a custom list using Power App while keep using the built-in SharePoint Create & Edit list forms. So we open the built-in View list form (by clicking on the list item inside the list view) >> then we click on "Customize with Power Apps ", as follow:-

[image]

but we have this question:-

1. Can we still use the SharePoint built-in list forms when creating & editing list items? while only customize (using Power App) the View/Display list form? as following the above steps will always show the Power App form even when we create or edit the list items.. while our intention was to only customize the View/Display list form only.. Any advice on this please? and if this is not achievable is there any workarounds to this ?
   Thanks

Comment: Do you need anything else in addition to my answer? Would be great if you could close this question, or state why the answer doesn't work for you.

Answer (score 2):

No, you cannot customize only the View form of a SharePoint list.

If you want to create a nicer viewing experience for SharePoint list items, but keep the editing experience as it is out of the box, you could create a stand-alone canvas app with PowerApps and serve that to your user base as the tool to view the SharePoint list items.

Or, you could customize the SharePoint form with PowerApps and create different screens for viewing and editing/new items. The techniques you need for this are outlined in the article linked below. Basically, you design different screens with different forms. Then you edit the SharePoint Integration properties to set a variable and navigate to the respective screen, for example:

```
OnNew – Set(SharePointFormMode, "CreateForm"); NewForm(CreateItemForm); Navigate(CreateScreen, ScreenTransition.None)

OnEdit – Set(SharePointFormMode, "EditForm"); EditForm(EditItemForm); Navigate(EditScreen, ScreenTransition.None)

OnView – Set(SharePointFormMode, "ShowForm"); ViewForm(ShowItemForm); Navigate(ShowScreen, ScreenTransition.None)
```

https://powerapps.microsoft.com/es-es/blog/separate-custom-forms/